# SQL Server Connected to Access FrontEnd, "This Recordset is not updateable".

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

So I started a new job, and have inherited an absolutely atrocious collection of databases tied to several access front ends. While attempting to create a testing server, I've run into an issue with the front ends. The previous developer created some access forms tied to tables and views within SQL Server 2008 r2. I'm trying to figure out why I cannot edit any of the values in any of the fields (text, combo boxes, lists, etc).

The View that the form is tied to is:

```
AuditQueries_UserTableForSelectionForms
```

The view looks similar to:

```
SELECT        TableForFormFields_1.FormSelectionID, TableForFormFields_1.JobPlan, TableForFormFields_1.Floor, TableForFormFields_1.Location, TableForFormFields_1.CHSR#, TableForFormFields_1.PanelName, 
                     TableForFormFields_1.PanelLetter, TableForFormFields_1.PanelCircuit, TableForFormFields_1.StartDate, TableForFormFields_1.EndDate, TableForFormFields_1.MigrationDate, TableForFormFields_1.JTag, 
                     TableForFormFields_1.MinBusRow, TableForFormFields_1.MaxBusRow, TableForFormFields_1.PlanID, TableForFormFields_1.Equip, TableForFormFields_1.CabinetJTag, 
                     Shared_Tables.dbo.username.[User]
FROM            Audit.TableForFormFields AS TableForFormFields_1 INNER JOIN
                     Shared_Tables.dbo.username ON TableForFormFields_1.FormSelectionID = Shared_Tables.dbo.username.[User]
```

TableFormFields is a table containing the default values for all the fields across the various forms, and it changes based on the logged in user. The logged in user is detected using the following view:

```
SELECT        CASE LEFT(SYSTEM_USER, 11) WHEN 'LIGHTHOUSE\' THEN SYSTEM_USER ELSE 'Webuser' END AS [User]
```

I have Googled the error, and all the documentation I've found doesn't seem very pertinent. There are other forms in the database tied to Tables that appear to work, and if I change the data source of the form to:

```
SELECT * FROM TableForFormFields AS TableForFormFields_1
```

Everything works as required. However, this diverges from the production environment, and I need to keep them the same, or at least as close as possible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They query (and thus the recordset which is populated by the query) is not updatable because of the `JOIN`. When you have a join the form or datasheet or whatever is using the query cannot resolve where your changes will go. If you want your recordset to be updatable you will need to reference one table.

The `ControlSource` for comboboxes/listboxes etc is the property which tells data where to be written when the record is saved. It is a field in the form's `RecordSource`.

A control's `RowSource` property is what tells the control what to display as available options.

In your case you should set the `RowSource` to the view which serves up the relevant data and set the `ControlSource` to the record in the table which will be updated.

Comment: So how could this be modified to correct this issue?

Comment: @Jdsfighter When that same view on the old server was the data source for the form, was the form editable?

Comment: Everything database wise between the production server and the testing server are identical, but the view doesn't work for whatever reason on my testing server.

Comment: We may not be on the same page.  If you create a link from Access to the `AuditQueries_UserTableForSelectionForms` view on the old server, and then open that link in Datasheet View, can you edit it?

Comment: OK.  If you create a similar link to `AuditQueries_UserTableForSelectionForms` on the new server, can you edit that one in Datasheet View?

Comment: I have to leave for a while.  But, unless you changed the view definition, the join is not the cause of the problem.  If the link to the new version of `AuditQueries_UserTableForSelectionForms` is not editable from Access, compare the permissions ... old vs. new ... on the view itself as well as any other objects the view depends on.

Comment: @HansUp you're right, it is much more likely a permissions issue at this point. Good questions.

Comment: If I modify the view and remove the join, and simply use a select statement on the UserTableForSelectionForms table only, it still does not work. But I'm unsure what sort of permission error might be occurring here. I'm not sure if it is access or sql server, or a mixture of both.

Comment: when you do that is that in your dev environment or prod? The permissions will all be in SQL server. Access doesn't have the ability to do permissions (unless you're using an old mdb which your not)

Comment: That is in the testing environment. Production works just fine.